# How to set default values on imported components in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-intl

Lets say I am using a `<FormattedNumber >` that I am importing from `react-intl`

It has a property called `minimumSignificantDigits`, so that if I set it all my numbers look awesome like `1.00`... great when you are working with currencies.. so I can use it like this:
`<FormattedNumber minimumSignificantDigits={3} value={somevar}>`

I have about 100 of these on the page and I don't want to keep setting this `minimumSignificantDigits` property on every single on of them, and then when the client changes his/her mind I have to update all of them.

Is there any way that I can set/override some default properties on that component when I import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously yes, make a wrapper around `<FormattedNumber>`

```
// TreeCharFormattedNumber.jsx
export default TreeCharFormattedNumber = ({ value }) => (
  <FormattedNumber  minimumSignificantDigits={3} value={value}>>
);

// YourComponent.jsx
import TreeCharFormattedNumber from "./TreeCharFormattedNumber";
...
<div>
   <TreeCharFormattedNumber value={myAwsomeValue} />
</div>
...
```

You can also put `TreeCharFormattedNumber` in the same file leaving `export default`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with your own component:

```
export const MyFormattedNumber = (props) => (
    <FormattedNumber minimumSignificantDigits={3} {...props}>
);
```

Now you can import it whenever it's needed, and everything you'll pass to `MyFormattedNumber` will be passed to the wrapped `FormattedNumber`:

```
<MyFormattedNumber value={3} />
```

You can easily override the default if you pass the property `minimumSignificantDigits`, because spreading the props can replace the default prop as well:

```
<MyFormattedNumber minimumSignificantDigits={15} value={somevar}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the imported component with another.

In this example, the default value for `minimumSignificantDigits` would be 3 with any other props passed through as is.  (This allows you to also override your default on a per component basis if required)

```
function FormattedNumberWithDefault(props) {
    return (
       <FormattedNumber minimumSignificantDigits={3} {...props}>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the following also works:

```
import React from 'react'
import {FormattedNumber} from 'react-intl'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

FormattedNumber.defaultProps = {
  style: 'decimal', 
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2,
}
```